# Help on DotNetNuke

Tags: layout, dotnetnuke

Does any body know how can i change the layout of a dotnetnuke website. I need to modify the standard layout

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom skin or modify the default skin that comes with the DNN installation. The default skin files are in [Website]\Portals_default\Skins\MinimalExtropy\ where [Website] is your DNN web site folder. If you are new to skinning and have a lot of questions, I am sure that the DNN forums will be helpful - [DNN Skinning forums](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/109/scope/threads/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by editing the CSS. I had similar issue, for which I used " inspect element" in google chrome that helped me in recognizing div elements and css properties. You can find css in portals_default\Skins\DarkKnight (or your own skin name) \skin.css

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to do anything outside of the CSS (ie, turn off the search bar on a page); then you have to have full access to the site -- open the site via FTP or download all the files, then you can modify the 'default' page, or the skin file you want to change. my suggestion is to make a 'copy' of the skin default page you want to change, give it a new name, and then save it back to the server.  When you go to change the 'skin' theme from the 'site manager' you will see your new skin page listed as an option. Modifying from the CMS does not allow you to modify the actual 'page', only its 'parts'.  There is also a starter kit available for Visual Studio, google "DNN Starter Kit" which you can create custom modules, skins and containers.